# MySQL, phpMyAdmin: TIMESTAMP Always Executes NOW Function

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, phpmyadmin

There's something very irritating going on with my TIMESTAMPS ...

I have a "createdat", "deletedat" and "updatedat" column in my Table... I've set my deletedat and updated at to NULL and DEFAULT NULL ... however, when a new record is added, the NOW() function is always executed for deletedat and updatedat instead of just leaving it as NULL.

So I end up with: 00:00:00 ...

Why isn't it just defaulting to NULL?

Here's my Table:
[image]

Here's when Inserting (notice the NOW function is selected):
[image]

The following SQL is executed:

```
INSERT INTO `MYTABLE_DEV`.`messages` (`id`, `fromUserId`, `toUserId`, `subject`, `body`, `createdat`, `updatedat`, `deletedat`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '3', 'Message', 'This is another message.', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NOW(), NOW());
```

Comment: It might help to post your DDL.

Comment: Is there perhaps a trigger making that modification?

Comment: There's nothing special going on... I haven't done anything to trigger this behavior.

Comment: When you execute that query, what does phpMyAdmin show as the SQL that was submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

Unlike other databases, in MySQL `TIMESTAMP` columns are **ALWAYS** updated with `now()` whenever the row is updated. This is a deliberate feature of the TIMESTAMP datatype.

Edit: Note that I am talking here about `TIMESTAMP`, *not* `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL` or any other variations.

What you want is a `DATETIME` datatype - they behave as normal columns.

Here's some test SQL to show its behaviour:

```
create table timestamp_datatype (id int, dt datetime, ts timestamp);
-- test 1: leaving ts to default - you get now()
insert into timestamp_datatype (id, dt) values (1, '2011-01-01 01:01:01'); 
-- test 2: trying to give ts a value - this works
insert into timestamp_datatype (id, dt, ts) values (2, '2011-01-01 01:01:01', '2011-01-01 01:01:01');
-- test 3: specifying null for ts - this doesn't work - you get now()
insert into timestamp_datatype (id, dt, ts) values (3, '2011-01-01 01:01:01', null);
-- test 4: updating the row - ts is updated too
insert into timestamp_datatype (id, dt, ts) values (4, '2011-01-01 01:01:01', '2011-01-01 01:01:01');
update timestamp_datatype set dt = now() where id = 4; -- ts is updated to now()
select * from timestamp_datatype;
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | dt                  | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2011-01-01 01:01:01 | 2011-07-05 09:50:24 |
|    2 | 2011-01-01 01:01:01 | 2011-01-01 01:01:01 |
|    3 | 2011-01-01 01:01:01 | 2011-07-05 09:50:24 |
|    4 | 2011-07-05 09:50:24 | 2011-07-05 09:50:24 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` columns are **not** always updated. Try creating a table with, for instance, a `VARCHAR` column and a `TIMESTAMP` column defined as `NULL DEFAULT NULL`. Insert a row, specifying only the `VARCHAR` field. The `TIMESTAMP` field will stay as `NULL`. Update the inserted row, again specifying only the `VARCHAR` field. Again, the `TIMESTAMP` will stay as `NULL`. Just tested with MySQL 5.1.

Comment: One thing to remember is that `ts TIMESTAMP` in the `CREATE TABLE` means `ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. If you want to use `NULL` values, this must be specified: `ts TIMESTAMP NULL`.

Comment: I will mention that although some of the statements above are false, DATETIME works just fine and does what it's supposed to do. I'll take the "news flash", as obnoxious as it seems.

Comment: All this said, the `TIMESTAMP` column type isn't the most logical, but the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html) tries to explain how the defaults and the auto-updates behave.

Comment: Yes, `TIMESTAMP` *are* always updated. `TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL` is not `TIMESTAMP`! As I said `TIMESTAMP` (ie WITHOUT any extra modifications) is always updated as per my post

Comment: @Bohemian: Right, sorry. Thought you referred to the `TIMESTAMP` column type in general.

Comment: This answer is collecting some downvotes - I would love to know why. Thx. (Please read all comments too)

Answer (score 2):

You are executing NOW() instead of setting null. Use this query:

```
INSERT INTO `MYTABLE_DEV`.`messages` (`id`, `fromUserId`, `toUserId`, `subject`, `body`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '3', 'Message', 'This is another message.');
```

or with all fields...

```
INSERT INTO `MYTABLE_DEV`.`messages` (`id`, `fromUserId`, `toUserId`, `subject`, `body`, `createdat`, `updatedat`, `deletedat`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '3', 'Message', 'This is another message.', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: The query is just what's run automatically... not what I'm constructed myself.

Answer (score 1):

Let it be here (little patch upcoming in 3.5.2 which compleatly solves this problem):
[the bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3521016&group_id=23067&atid=377408)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug/feature in phpMyAdmin. Have a look at [this bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=1334627&group_id=23067&atid=377408), and especially the comment added at 2010-06-13 11:06:47 UTC. The interesting part:

> You can question however, the default value of NOW() in the selectionbox
>   when doing an INSERT/UPDATE, when the default value of the timestamp field
>   is set to NULL. This is maybe not what you would suspect when setting the
>   default to NULL.

If this is true, I guess that's just the way phpMyAdmin works. I don't use phpMyAdmin myself, so I have no personal experience from this.